# JavaScript template engine that maps HTML-forms based on name

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, asp.net-mvc-4, template-engine

I'm using backbone js for handling my views and models but I wish to render the templates using Html.EditorFor in ASP.NET MVC. This is because my forms are dynamically created based on a C# class. I have only tried underscore for JavaScript templating but it requires markup in the value field like this `<%=heading%>` and that is not an option for me. I need a template engine that can map my form using the name of each form component, or if there are some other view engine that can render the same markup that works for both the server and the js template engine.

**UPDATE**

In my view I'm using Html.EditorFor like this:

```
@foreach (var type in Html.GetAvailablePageModels()) {
    var content = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IContent;
    <script id="view-template-@type.Name" type="text/html">
        @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
            @Html.EditorFor(x => content)
            <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
        }
    </script>
}
```

Then in my backbone view I'm doing something like this:

```
var PageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/page'
});
var page = new PageModel({ id: 'articles/85' });
page.fetch();

var EditView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('div#main'),

    initialize: function () {
        this.template = _.template($('#view-template-Article').html());
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON())); // <-- set the values correct in my pre rendered form
        return this;
    }

});

window.editView = new EditView({ model: page });
```

In the above code where I bind the model to the template I need to make sure that the field called heading binds to the correct form field with name="heading".

Comment: I'd look at something like Backbone.Stickit potentially, as it looks like you might want 2-way binding to a Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way underscore templates work:

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate : /\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g
};
```

Now you can write HTML templates like this:

```
This is a message: {{message}}
```

Instead of the old-school `<%= message %>` style. This will let you generate the templates you want from your Razor views on the server. I did this on a project once and it worked out really well.

Comment: That seems to work great! How did you make your Razor views render the correct HtmlFieldName? If I use something like <input type="text" value="{{@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)}}" /> in my view the result is printed like this: <input type="text" value="{{content.Heading}}" /> but my JSON contains does not contain the content prefix. Is there a way to remove the prefix automatically or do I need to do this manually?

Comment: i don't remember, honestly. that was over a year ago and i haven't worked w/ .net / razor since then... sorry

Comment: Okay, I'll start a new question about that. Thanks for your help!